# how can I deactivate a form button field for file upload when a selection is made in drop down menu filed without using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have implemented a crispy form and crispy form helper to render a form. The form contains a drop down selection menu and a file submission button. However I want to deactivate the file submission button when the selection "File not required" is made in the drop down menu.

However I want all this to be done before the form submission button is pressed (i.e. before invoking POST method).

I'm trying to avoid any Jquery and AJAX implementations. Is there any Django way of doing this using Django Forms, views or Django Crispy Forms.

Crispy forms has HTML object for its layout class. Is there any way of doing above mentioned in using HTML objects or any other objects of layout class.

Below is the chunk of Django Form that is rendered in its respective template.

```
self.fields[field_name] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, label='')
        file_name = str(customer_Id)
        self.fields[file_name] = forms.FileField(label=_("Attach PDF"), required=True)

        self.helper.layout.append(Layout(
            HTML('<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>'.format(customerId, name)),
            field_name,

            HTML('</td><td>'),
            file_name,
            HTML('</td></tr>'),

        ))
    self.helper.layout.append(Layout(HTML('</tbody></table>')))
```

Comment: you can do this in pure Javascript, but this can't be done in pure Django. Django only sends data to your template on a page render; it doesn't come back again until you submit the POST data.

Comment: Thanks @brno32. I have sorted that out by server side coding in views.py.